# CoArbitrary in Haskell

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I am working through the Haskell Book and have come to the point of writing an Arbitrary instance for `newType Comp`. The code is below

```
instance Show (Comp a) where
    show f = "Unicorns!!"

newtype Comp a =
    Comp { unComp :: (a -> a) }

instance (Semigroup a) => S.Semigroup (Comp a) where
    (Comp fx) <> (Comp fy) = Comp (fx . fy)

instance (CoArbitrary a, Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (Comp a) where
    arbitrary = do
        f <- Test.QuickCheck.arbitrary
        return (Comp f)

type CompAssoc = String -> Comp String -> Comp String -> Comp String -> Bool

compAssoc :: (S.Semigroup a, Eq a) => a -> Comp a -> Comp a -> Comp a -> Bool
compAssoc v a b c = (unComp (a <> (b <> c)) $ v) == (unComp ((a <> b) <> c) $ v)
```

and tested with

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    quickCheck (compAssoc :: CompAssoc)
```

My question revolves around the Arbitrary instance. It is generating a function to be passed to `return (Comp f)`. I understand (though not fully why) that this has to be scoped to CoArbitrary. But if that thing passed to `return (Comp f)` is `CoArbitrary`, how can it also be `Arbitrary`? I guess it seems to be like these constraints both refer to the pass/return type of the function *and the function itself*. I'm a little confused.

Comment: You need the Coarbitrary constraint because the Arbitrary instance for functions requires it (to see why, look at how the Arbitrary instance is defined). However, there is nothing preventing a type from being both Arbitrary and Coarbitrary (indeed, most types have both instances). Why does this seem contradictory to you?

Comment: I think I got confused with ` Arbitrary (Comp a)`

I assumed the `a` was a type like in `Comp String`, as is used in `CompAssoc`, but the `a` here represents the function that you pass when constructing a `Comp`. You only use the concrete types when declaring functions. I guess I mixed up type constructors and data constructors.

Comment: Still confused. I changed the data constructor to `Compp` and it still requires the type constructor for the Arbitrary declaration. but the Type Constructor takes a type like `String` or whatever has a Semigroup instance. But here we are trying to generate functions, i.e. the thing passed to the data constructor. How can we limit `Comp a` (the data constructor to need `CoArbitrary` when it expects something like `String` which is something that has a Semigroup instance?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see where your confusion lies. Is there a specific thing you are trying to accomplish which you are having trouble with?

Comment: no, just understand why the test passes. I think I am understanding that by putting the CoArbitrary restraint on the `a` going to `Comp`, that is restraining the arg and return type of the `unComp` function, saying that I must be able to generate a function that takes a `type a`

Comment: or more broadly, if I were to not have `CoArbitrary a` as a restraint, but just `Arbitrary a`, then I can return a random `a` value. But when I add `CoArbitrary a`, the random value that is returned is a function that can accept an `a`. That is, `CoArbitrary` speaks about returning a function that *accepts* values of a certain type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a *beginner's, high-level*, very probably **incorrect in the underlying details** explanation of the relationship between `Arbitrary` and `CoArbitrary`.

The article https://begriffs.com/posts/2017-01-14-design-use-quickcheck.html gives you a better explanation but it uses Applicative and Functor and I haven't gotten there yet as I am still on the SemiGroup chapter of "The Haskell Book".

If you want to generate a function from `a -> b`, `b` must have an instance of `Arbitrary`. We're going to be generating random stuff anyways, so we need a `Gen b` as usual. But we need to *vary* this `b` just like a normal function would, that is, in the sense of if I pass a different value to a function like `double`, I'd expect a different response. But how can we *vary* a generator based on some random `a`? Well, if we think about the way we generate random `b`s in the first place, it has to do with `numbers`. I.e. if I want a random `b` (say, Int), I just generate a random number. Easy peasy. Random string? Start with random numbers, convert them to ASCII chars. Same with any other data type you want, and quickcheck provides a lot of `Arbitrary` instances that do just that.

OK, so at the base it is numbers. 
We could change those numbers by getting some other number and then, say, multiplying/subtracting/adding/dividing. Or any other math operation. But how do we get that other number? That's where `CoArbitrary` comes in! If I mark a type as needing to have an instance of `CoArbitrary`, effectively I am saying "I need to be able to reduce your type down to a number so that I can **vary** (add/mult/etc) the Generator for type `b`. So if type `a` is a string, for ex., reduce that string to a number, pass it to the gen for `type b` in order to let the Gen for type `b` do the `mult/add/etc` operation on the **number(s)** it would use to generate a `b`.